# How to update a document using elasticsearch-py?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

Does anyone have an example for how to use update?  It's documented [here](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.update), but the documentation is unclear and doesn't include a working example.  I've tried the following:

```
coll = Elasticsearch()
coll.update(index='stories-test',doc_type='news',id=hit.meta.id,
                body={"stanford": 1, "parsed_sents": parsed })
```

and I get

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: 
TransportError(400, u'ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;]')
```

I would like to update using a partial doc, but the update method doesn't take any argument named 'doc' or 'document'.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to enclose your body inside a "doc" field. The correct way of doing a partial update with elasticsearch-py goes like this:

```
coll = Elasticsearch()
coll.update(index='stories-test',doc_type='news',id=hit.meta.id,
                body={"doc": {"stanford": 1, "parsed_sents": parsed }})
```

Comment: and what if use this with update_by_query api :) There should be no id parameter I guess.. Or ?

Comment: No that's different. update-by-query is an external plugin, not something that is supported by the elasticsearch-py library.

Comment: Is it possible use update_by_query in python with http request?

Comment: update by query for elasticsearch-py documentation is here https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.update_by_query

Comment: If you are using elasticsearch 7x - remember to remove doc_type

Comment: Can you please tell on how to update the list?? Like what argument to use @Val

Comment: @BrownBatman what list? please don't hesitate to create a new thread with your specific issue, as this thread is closed